# Passing pointer to function as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*HandlerFunc)(int, int);
HandlerFunc  mr;
HandlerFunc mm()
{
    return mr;
}

void sample(int a, int b, HandlerFunc func)
{
}

void main()
{
     sample(1, 2, mm);
}
```

Here I'm trying to pass a function of type `HandlerFunc` to another function, but I am getting an error:

> Error :*: cannot convert parameter 3 from `'void (__cdecl *(void))(int,int)'` to `'void (__cdecl *)(int,int)'`

If I type cast as `sample(1, 2, (HandlerFunc)mm);` everything works fine.
Can anyone tell what is the way to solve the error issue?

Comment: Do you want `mm()` to return the function pointer, or want to define `mm` as the type HandlerFunc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HandlerFunc mm()
{...}
```

should be:

```
void mm(int, int)
{...}
```

Your function `sample()` takes a pointer to function(*you `typedef`d as `HandlerFunc`*) as last argument.
The address of the function you pass as this argument must match the type of the function to which it is a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

No, no, you've confused the types. `mm` is a function that returns a function pointer of the appropriate type. However, `mm` itself is *not* of the appropriate type - it doesn't accept any parameters.

You should pass `mr` in main, or pass `mm()` (that is - call mm and pass the return value)

Answer (score 0):

The code in main should be:

```
sample(1,2,mm());
```

as mm returns a HandlerFunc, it isn't one itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
HandlerFunc mm() 
{     
   return mr; 
}
```

This means `nm` is function which will not receive any agruments(`void`), and it will reutrn a pointer to function of type `void (*)(int, int)`

so that only you are getting that error.